# Add Data to MySQL Database from an HTML Form

Tags: mysql, forms

HI all i've a basic Web Form for putting data into a mysql database, I created code to report if i was connected to my Database correctly and it was so on completion of the form i tested it and it seems to do what i expected but when i goto my database no data was actually entered?

my form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" method="POST" action="data.php" onsubmit="return(validate())">

         <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-5" style=" margin-left:5%">
          <div class="form-group" >
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name"  placeholder="Enter your name!">
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Enter email">
              </div>
               <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Pass" placeholder="Enter password">
              </div>     
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-5"  style="float:right; margin-right:5%">
               <div class="form-group">
             <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Num" onsubmit="return(phonenumber(myForm.Num))" placeholder="Enter phone no.">
             </div>
              <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Comment" placeholder="Any comments?">
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

data.php

```
<?

define('DB_NAME', 'Demo');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
if( $_POST )
{
  $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("Demo", $con);

  $Name1 = $_POST['Name'];
  $Email1 = $_POST['Email'];
  $Pass1 = $_POST['Pass'];
  $Num1 = $_POST['Num'];
  $Comment1 = $_POST['Comment'];

  $Name = mysql_real_escape_string($Name);
  $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($Email);
  $Pass = mysql_real_escape_string($Pass);
  $Num = mysql_real_escape_string($Num);
  $Comment = mysql_real_escape_string($Comment);



  $sql = "
  INSERT INTO Demo ( `Name`, `Email`, `Password`,`Contact_num`,
    `Comment`) VALUES ('$Name1',
    '$Email1', '$Pass1', '$Num1','$Comment1'
    )";

mysql_query($sql);


  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: echo your $sql query and run this query in phpmyadmin  and check the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dbhost  = "localhost";
$dbuser  = "root";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost , $dbuser);
mysql_select_db("Demo",$conn);

$Name1 = $_POST['Name'];
$Email1 = $_POST['Email'];
$Pass1 = $_POST['Pass'];
$Num1 = $_POST['Num'];
$Comment1 = $_POST['Comment'];


echo $Name1.$Email1.$Pass1.$Num1.$Comment1; //this is to check whether you are getting all the values or not. 
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME ( `Name`, `Email`, `Password`,`Contact_num`,  `Comment`) VALUES ('$Name1',
'$Email1', '$Pass1', '$Num1','$Comment1'
)";

mysql_query($sql);


  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Kindly consider that the Insert Query should have the name of the table, not the database.